# Remove "product information, reviews, tags" block from product page

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, blocks, product-view

I am trying to remove a certain block from my product page in Magento, but can't seem to find where I should delete it. I think it's somewhere in the XML files, but since I'm not that good of a web-developer, I figured it's stupid to just try to delete some files.

In the Magento admin I already disabled the 'tags' function `(admin -> system -> configuration -> advanced -> disable Mage_Tag)`, but I can't find where to delete the entire block.

The block circled in red in the picture is the block I'm trying to delete. So also 'productomschrijving' and 'extra informatie'.

[image: The block I'm trying to delete]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should have to create `local.xml` file inside your frontend theme folder `app/design/frontend/[your_package]/[your_theme] (if you haven't already)`

And insert the following lines there

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<layout version="0.1.0">

<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info.tabs">
        <action method="unsetChild">
            <child>description</child>
        </action>
        <action method="unsetChild">
            <child>additional</child>
        </action>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>

</layout>
```

you can change your  tag name to your product description and extra information tag given in theme.

Comment: Thanks. Only this just removed the tags and product description. The extra information is still showing. Do you perhaps know how this could still appear? Because I'd personally say that that would be removed by
<action method="unsetChild">
            <child>product_additional_data</child>
        </action>

Comment: try to change <child>additional</child> in second remove. hopefully it will work for you

Comment: @Jennie, i am glad to help you.

Comment: How do you remore "review" tab just for certain products ? Like gift cards product ?

Comment: @sagarsapkota, add question instead of comment will do my best to help you

Answer (score 7):

Admin Panel -> System -> Advanced -> Mage_Tag = "Disable"

Answer (score 5):

Create `local.xml` and paste the below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<layout>
  <default>
     <remove name="product_tag_list" />
  </default>
<layout>
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove the whole tab area and not single tabs as suggested by [@liyacat](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/63159/243), use this code in your theme's `layout/local.xml`:

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <remove name="product.info.tabs">
</catalog_product_view>
```

Answer (score 0):

GO to adminPanel, click on Widget and search for Tag,  Product Review, Custom Tag, Now Remove the layout. It Will Work

Comment: Widgets are not related to these product tabs. This can only be done via  layout XML as far as I know

Answer (score 0):

Change The block name to "product.tags" if you want to remove tags.

Hopefully it will work for you!